ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 64, 32, 1), found shape=(32, 32, 1)
I tried debugging and added print statements, to my surprise it is of correct shape, yet the program says its not of the shape
Shape: (None, 64, 32, 1)
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
 image (InputLayer)          [(None, 64, 32, 1)]       0

 Conv1 (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 32, 32)        320

 pool1 (MaxPooling2D)        (None, 32, 16, 32)        0

 batch_normalization (BatchN  (None, 32, 16, 32)       128
 ormalization)

 reshape (Reshape)           (None, 32, 512)           0

 dense2 (Dense)              (None, 32, 16)            8208

 batch_normalization_1 (Batc  (None, 32, 16)           64
 hNormalization)

 bidirectional (Bidirectiona  (None, 32, 256)          148480
 l)

 dense3 (Dense)              (None, 32, 42)            10794

=================================================================
Total params: 167,994
Trainable params: 167,898
Non-trainable params: 96
_________________________________________________________________
None
Input Shape: (64, 32, 1)
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Arabic-Handwritten-OCR\Arabic-Handwritten-OCR\inference.py", line 156, in <module>
    preds = prediction_model.predict(batch_images)
  File "C:\Users\User\miniconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file42woagrz.py", line 15, in tf__predict_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:  ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 64, 32, 1), found shape=(32, 32, 1)**

I tried to check for the shape of the input to the model, and it literally says (64, 32, 1) but the traceback says found shape=(32,32,1), why is it? how can I solve this?

The error message indicates that the input shape expected by the model is (None, 64, 32, 1), but the actual shape provided during prediction is (32, 32, 1). This inconsistency suggests that there might be an issue with the input data shape or how it's being passed to the model.There are some points that you need to check so that you can resolved the issue Check Input Data Shape:-Verify the shape of the input data (batch_images) before passing it to the model. Ensure that it matches the expected shape (64, 32, 1),

Check Model Input Layer: Verify that the input layer of your model is configured correctly to accept inputs of shape (None, 64, 32, 1).If the input data shape is correct, check the data preprocessing steps to ensure that the data is correctly reshaped or normalized before feeding it to the correct shape.If you're still unable to resolve it, providing more details about your data preprocessing.
